# General Memoization function in F#

Tags: f#, dynamic-programming, fibonacci

I have a question about this general memoization function in Fsharp:

```
let memoize f =
    let dict = new Dictionary<_,_>()
    fun n ->
        match dict.TryGetValue(n) with
        | (true, v) -> 
            v
        | _ ->
            let temp = f(n)
            dict.Add(n, temp)
            temp
```

If I use a fibonacci number as an example:

```
let rec fib = memoize(fun n ->
    if n = 1 then 1
    elif n = 2 then 1
    else fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2) )
```

so every iteration will create a new dictionary, and wouldn't the dictionary with the mapping always be cleared out? However, the function does show that it creates a dictionary with all the nodes, can you please elaborate on this, thanks in advance!

**Edit**:

I tried to modify the Fibonacci function into

```
let rec fib i = memoize(fun n ->
    if n = 1 then 1
    elif n = 2 then 1
    else fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2) ) i
```

Because I want to get rid of the warning(for the previous fibonacci function):

> This and other recursive references to the object(s) being defined will be checked for initialization-soundness
> at runtime through the use of a delayed reference. This is because you are defining one or more recursive objects, rather than recursive functions.

then it will everytime initiate every time the dictionary (it's not memoized), cannot wrap my head around it

Comment: It doesn't create a new dictionary. `memoize` returns the inner function `n`. Every time you call `fib`, you're actually calling the `n` function which uses the single dictionary created when `memoize` was called

Comment: but the `fib` funtion also calls `memoize`, won't this generate a new dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want [a memoizing y-combinator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3459864).

If you break up the recursion in that you don't recurse directly and call a function passed as argument instead, you can easily access the intermediate results for memoization.

```
let fib f = function
| 1 | 2 -> 1
| n -> f (n - 1) + f (n - 2)
```

This function can be run with the standard [y-combinator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator). As no memoization is involved, it will take ages to complete.

```
let rec Y f x = f (Y f) x

Y fib 45
// val it : int = 1134903170
```

The memoized version returns almost immediately.

```
let memoize f =
    let d = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<_,_>()
    let rec g x =
        match d.TryGetValue x with
        | true, res -> res
        | _ -> let res = f g x in d.Add(x, res); res
    g

memoize fib 45
// val it : int = 1134903170
```